# Full documentation of viewer object

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am following [transform tutorial](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/moving-visually-your-components-in-the-viewer-using-the-transformtool.html) . At many places in the code, viewer.impl, viewer.toolController are used. I checked documentation of [Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/) but I don't find all the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming components is not exposed to the public API unfortunately, so the blog post relies on some undocumented members and methods of the viewer. Those are accessed through `viewer.impl.XXX` and you won't find those in the documentation. If you have any questions on how to get something done take a look at our [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog) or feel free to post your questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`viewer.toolController`is an instance of another separated class called `ToolController`. Here is the documentation:

https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/toolcontroller/

Hope it help.